# Tooltips break when I sort the data points chronologically

Tags: highcharts

In order to chart the results of a Transducer Deviation test, I have to sort the data points chronologically (the order in which they are returned by the test).

So the order that the data points are in is important to the engineers. The chart looks exactly like what the engineers want. HOWEVER, it seems that putting the data points in this order breaks the tooltip mechanism.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Is there a way to draw a chart like this AND be able to see the tooltips?

Here is my chart in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msmonroe72/Dd7Nf/4/).

Here is my chart code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                width: 760,
                height: 628,
                style: {
                    margin: '0 auto'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Transducer Deviation (%FSO)'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: 'PSIA'
                },
                showLastLabel: true,
                },
            yAxis: {
                max:.15,
                min:-.15,
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature'
                },
                lineWidth: 2,
                tickInterval: 0.03,
                plotLines:[{
                    color: '#ff0000',
                    width: 2,
                    value: 0.1
                },{
                    color: '#ff0000',
                    width: 2,
                    value: -0.1
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        "<b>"+this.series.name + ":</b> " + this.x +'°, '+ this.y + " PSIA" ;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    marker: {
                        enable: false
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                        name:'TEMP7 = 75.00',
                        data: [[0.009558,0.067672],[1.499949,0.026805],[3.000044,0.065205],[4.499968,0.092226],[6.000035,0.112667],[7.500029,0.112462],[8.999997,0.097762],[10.500043,0.084260],[11.999973,0.045674],[13.500054,-0.002144],[14.999980,-0.071104],
                            [13.500024,-0.056812],[11.999940,-0.032214],[10.499979,-0.035400],[9.000065,-0.038020],[7.500023,-0.047703],[6.000001,-0.057745],[4.499986,-0.071516],[3.000016,-0.100930],[1.500019,-0.127485],[0.009707,-0.063658]
                            ]
                    }]
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Data need to be sorted via x ascending, so in your case you need to use two separated series or sort data properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the timestamp as the x value, and add the required numerical data to the data point as an extra variable.

This way you can have the data sorted properly, but also display the data you need in the tooltip.

To see how to provide and display the extra variable, see this old `example`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fbMQf/